# Is there a way to generically mock the DbSet.Find method with Moq?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, entity-framework-6, moq

I'm currently using an extension method to generically mock DbSets as a list:

```
    public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
        var mockDbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        mockDbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(queryable.GetEnumerator());
        mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>(sourceList.Add);
        mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Remove(It.IsAny<T>())).Returns<T>(x => { if (sourceList.Remove(x)) return x; else return null; } );

        return mockDbSet.Object;
    }
```

However, I can't figure out a way to mock the Find method, which searches based on the table's primary key.  I could do it at a specific level for each table because I can inspect the database, get the PK, and then just mock the Find method for that field.  But then I can't use the generic method.

I suppose I could also go add to the partial classes that EF auto-generated to mark which field is the PK with an attribute or something.  But we have over 100 tables and it makes the code more difficult to manage if you're relying on people to manually maintain this.

Does EF6 provide any way of finding the primary key, or does it only know dynamically after it's connected to the database?

Comment: are you looking for something like this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25199983/5048049) otherwise could you explain better what are you looking for?

Comment: That's the first alternative I described.  That's making a specific mock just for the ActiveLoan set, rather than a generic mock for any generic set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After pondering this for awhile, I think I've found the "best" solution currently available.  I just have a series of if statements that directly checks the type in the extension method.  Then I cast to the type I need to set the find behavior and cast it back to generic when I'm done.  It's only pseudo-generic, but I can't think of anything else better.

```
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyFirstSet))
        {
            mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(x => (sourceList as List<MyFirstSet>).FirstOrDefault(y => y.MyFirstSetKey == (Guid)x[0]) as T);
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(MySecondSet))
        {
            mockDbSet.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(x => (sourceList as List<MySecondSet>).FirstOrDefault(y => y.MySecondSetKey == (Guid)x[0]) as T);
        }
        ...
```

Comment: Nice.  Since all my entities have the same primary key of "Id", I was able to make this more generic by replacing "y.MySetKey" with "y.GetType().GetProperty("Id").GetValue(y)".

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell, there is no 'best practice' answer to this question, but here's how I've approached it. I've added an optional parameter to the `AsDbSet` method which identifies the primary key, then the `Find` method can be mocked up easily.

```
public static DbSet<T> AsDbSet<T>(this List<T> sourceList, Func<T, object> primaryKey = null) where T : class
{
    //all your other stuff still goes here

    if (primaryKey != null)
    {
        mockSet.Setup(set => set.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns((object[] input) => sourceList.SingleOrDefault(x => (Guid)primaryKey(x) == (Guid)input.First()));
    }

    ...
}
```

I've written this on the assumption of a single guid being used as primary key as that seemed to be how you're working, but the principle should be easy enough to adapt if you need more flexibility for composite keys, etc.

Comment: Good job! Suggestion: if you use `primaryKey(x).Equals(input.First())` instead of `(Guid)primaryKey(x) == (Guid)input.First()` it may works for other types of primaryKey like integer, etc. and not particularly for Guid.

Comment: Good idea, that does look like a more flexible approach than I went for. Thanks Mahdi!

Answer (score 0):

I ended in the following class:

```
public static class DbSetMocking
{
    #region methods

    public static IReturnsResult<TContext> ReturnsDbSet<TEntity, TContext>( this IReturns<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>> setup, ICollection<TEntity> entities, Func<object[], TEntity> find = null )
        where TEntity : class where TContext : DbContext
    {
        return setup.Returns( CreateMockSet( entities, find ).Object );
    }

    private static Mock<DbSet<T>> CreateMockSet<T>( ICollection<T> data, Func<object[], T> find )
        where T : class
    {
        var queryableData = data.AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup( m => m.Provider ).Returns( queryableData.Provider );
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup( m => m.Expression ).Returns( queryableData.Expression );
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup( m => m.ElementType ).Returns( queryableData.ElementType );
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup( m => m.GetEnumerator() ).Returns( queryableData.GetEnumerator() );

        mockSet.SetupData( data, find );

        return mockSet;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Which can be used:

```
private static MyRepository SetupRepository( ICollection<Type1> type1s, ICollection<Type2> type2s )
{
    var mockContext = new Mock<MyDbContext>();

    mockContext.Setup( x => x.Type1s ).ReturnsDbSet( type1s, o => type1s.SingleOrDefault( s => s.Secret == ( Guid ) o[ 0 ] ) );
    mockContext.Setup( x => x.Type2s ).ReturnsDbSet( type2s, o => type2s.SingleOrDefault( s => s.Id == ( int ) o[ 0 ] ) );

    return new MyRepository( mockContext.Object );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using now Entity Framework Core 2, and this solution works fine to me.

At first, I will find the primary key by using the class name with the suffix “Id”. (If you follow other convention you must change it to fit your necessity.)

```
        //Find primary key. Here the PK must follow the convention "Class Name" + "Id" 
        Type type = typeof(T);
        string colName = type.Name + "Id";
        var pk = type.GetProperty(colName);
        if (pk == null)
        {
            colName = type.Name + "ID";
            pk = type.GetProperty(colName);
        }
```

Now that you know the Pk, you can support the Find with the following code

```
        dbSet.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns((object[] id) =>
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "t");
            var col = Expression.Property(param, colName);
            var body = Expression.Equal(col, Expression.Constant(id[0]));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
            return queryable.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
        });
```

So, the complete code for generically mock supporting DbSet.Find you can see below:

```
public static DbSet<T> GetQueryableMockDbSet<T>(List<T> sourceList) where T : class
    {
        var queryable = sourceList.AsQueryable();
        var dbSet = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();

        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(queryable.Provider);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(queryable.Expression);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(queryable.ElementType);
        dbSet.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => queryable.GetEnumerator());
        dbSet.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<T>())).Callback<T>((s) => sourceList.Add(s));

        //Find primary key. Here the PK must follow the convention "Class Name" + "Id" 
        Type type = typeof(T);
        string colName = type.Name + "Id";
        var pk = type.GetProperty(colName);
        if (pk == null)
        {
            colName = type.Name + "ID";
            pk = type.GetProperty(colName);
        }

        dbSet.Setup(x => x.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns((object[] id) =>
        {
            var param = Expression.Parameter(type, "t");
            var col = Expression.Property(param, colName);
            var body = Expression.Equal(col, Expression.Constant(id[0]));
            var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, param);
            return queryable.FirstOrDefault(lambda);
        });

        return dbSet.Object;

    } //GetQueryableMockDbSet
```

Comment: While I really like the idea of building the expression up to do the filter, you are making an assumption about the primary key that makes this answer very specific and somewhat limited. I would have suggested using reflection to find the member that has the primary key attribute and use that member name.

Comment: Hi @Nkosi, you are right. I "highlighted" the part of code about the primary key because I know that this must be changed if someone don't use the entity framework convention to create pk's. Identify "who" is the PK is the point of attention and even using reflection could be difficult or impossible to identify the   PK. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add a parameter to specify the key of the entity:

```
public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> Setup<TContext, TEntity, TKey>(this Mock<TContext> mockContext,
    Expression<Func<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>>> expression, List<TEntity> sourceList,
    Func<TEntity, TKey> id)
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> data = sourceList.AsQueryable();
    Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> mock = data.BuildMockDbSet();

    // make adding to and searching the list work
    mock.Setup(d => d.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback(add(sourceList));
    mock.Setup(d => d.Find(It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns<object[]>(s => find(sourceList, id, s));

    // make context.Add() and Find() work
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Add(It.IsAny<TEntity>())).Callback(add(sourceList));
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Find<TEntity>(It.IsAny<object[]>()))
        .Returns<object[]>(s => find(sourceList, id, s));
    mockContext.Setup(x => x.Find(typeof(TEntity), It.IsAny<object[]>()))
        .Returns<Type, object[]>((t, s) => find(sourceList, id, s));
    mockContext.Setup(expression).Returns(mock.Object);
    return mock;
}

private static Action<TEntity> add<TEntity>(IList<TEntity> sourceList)
    where TEntity : class
{
    return s => sourceList.Add(s);
}

private static TEntity find<TEntity, TKey>(IList<TEntity> sourceList, Func<TEntity, TKey> id, object[] s) where TEntity : class
{
    return sourceList.SingleOrDefault(e => id(e).Equals(s[0]));
}
```

You can use it as

```
mockContext.Setup(m => m.Users, users, x => x.UsedId);
```

The BuildMockDbSet comes from the MockQueryable library (available from NuGet).

---

**Edit:** By the way, if you really do not want to specify the key everytime you call the above function, and you know most of your keys are of type int, you can create another overload like:

```
public static Mock<DbSet<TEntity>> Setup<TContext, TEntity>(this Mock<TContext> mockContext,
    Expression<Func<TContext, DbSet<TEntity>>> expression, List<TEntity> sourceList)
    where TEntity : class
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    return Setup(mockContext, expression, sourceList, x => x.GetKey<int>());
}
```

where GetKey is implemented by the extension methods:

```
public static object? GetKey(this object entity)
{
    PropertyInfo keyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperties().Where(prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(KeyAttribute))).SingleOrDefault();

    if (keyInfo == null)
        return null;

    return keyInfo.GetValue(entity);
}

public static TKey GetKey<TKey>(this object entity)
{
    return (TKey)GetKey(entity);
}
```

So now you can call it simply as

```
var mockUsers = mockContext.Setup(m => m.Users, users);
```